# Can't install Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, live-usb, intel

I'm new to linux. I've tried already installing dozens of other distros and none of them works. I hope I can get at least Ubuntu running, but even Ubuntu is stuck at this message: `Starting rtkit-daemon.service - Realtimekit Scheduling Policy Service`, I don't know what to do. It's not even booting into liveusdb mode

I have an Nvidia GPU and Intel CPU, trying to boot into Ubuntu from a USB stick

My specs:

- GPU: KFA2 RTX 3080 TI
- CPU: Intel Core i7-13700K
- RAM: XPG SPECTRIX D50 (32GB, 3600 MHz)
- Motherboard: MSI PRO Z690-A
- Harddrive: 500GB 5200 RPM
- USB Stick: 64 GB

P.S:

- I tried googling, but no solutions found
- Balena etcher failed to flash my USB stick for the fist time, but I tried again and it worked for the second time

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer? Knowing how much RAM and disk space you have will also be useful, as this will make it easier to narrow down possible reasons for why you cannot install the OS 

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! I've edited the post

Comment: Please also be specific with details of your Ubuntu 23.04; ie. is this a Ubuntu 23.04 Server install (using the `subiquity` installer), or a Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop install (here there are two choices of installer selected when you download the ISO; so which did you use? `ubuntu-desktop-installer` or the *legacy* `ubiquity` installer).  If it's desktop, did you try both installers? or only one; if so which one...  ie. please provide full details.  Have you verified the ISO write to your media? using another box or script?  (*you may not know how I suspect*)  Did you try safe graphics?

Comment: Can you [verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) and then start over following the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)? You have a very slow hard drive compared to the rest of your specs. Are you sure you're waiting enough time to let each step complete?

Answer (score 0):

I always use Rufus (Rufus 4.0 currently) to write my live USBs. Has never failed me. Also be aware that only a few distros (Ubuntu and OpenSuse for isntance) support Secure Boot. If you have secure boot enabled in BIOS, any non supported live distro will fail to load.